# How to create SQLite database in UTF-8 encoding

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, utf-8, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a Windows Store app (C#) using a SQLite database.

### Issue

If I have a special chars in a row like "qwerôty", when my app retrieve this value, the string object contains "qwerty" (without this special char).

### Database creation

I create my database with the **sqlite3** utility, then I write all my queries (create table, insert into...) in a file (UTF-8 encoded) and I copy&paste all the queries in the command prompt of sqlite3.

When I do a **select * from table** I see "qwerôty", but once in my app, the string does'nt contains the "ô".

### In-app code

Here is how I retrieve my data from the SQLite database :

```
private SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DbPath);
return await conn.Table<BusinessObject>().ToListAsync();
```

The string property is within the BusinessObject object

### My guess

I think the sqlite file that I create with **sqlite3** is not encoded in UTF-8. When I open it with the Windows built-in notepad and I do a "sav as", the selected encoding is ANSI. But I can't find how to create the database encoded in UTF-8.

If you have any idea of what is my issue, thanks in advance.

Rafi

Comment: I've juste tried to populate my database with SQLiteSpy and all the special chars are well read from my app. So it let me think that the issue comes from the sqlite3 tool, but I don't have a real explaination. I'll let this post unanswered until someone find a good reason. Thanks, Rafi.

Comment: Notepad is text (decoded) the save as encoding I think is just for the save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from Notepad as Paparazzi stated